# How can I update the time when the same item is added to the list box?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, observablecollection

I want to update an existing item when the same item is added in the list box. In the current code, the same value is added to the list box.

When adding a new item using "CollectionChanged + = Eevnt_CollectionChanged", do I need to check and delete existing items and add new items?

Here is the code:

```
public class Item: ModelBase
{
    private string _nowDate;
    public String NOWDATE 
    { 
         get { return _nowDate; }
         set { _nowDate = value; OnPropertyChanged("NOWDATE"); }
    }

    private string _name;
    public String Name 
    {
         get { return _name; } 
         set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } 
    }
}


private ObservableCollection<Item> _item;
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
{
    get { return _item; }

    set
    {
        _item= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}

... some code ...

while(true){
    ...

    Item.Insert(0, new Item
    {
        NOWDATE = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateformat),
        Name = itemName     
    }

    ...
}
```

Figure 1 shows the current list box results.
[image]

I want to display only the most recent one, as shown in Figure 2.
[image]

Please let me know if there is a good way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Or just update the properties of the existing item from the values of the new item, without adding the new item to the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to check if the item exists.

Don't forget to use the Linq library.

```
using System.Linq;

//Search the list to see if the name exists
//Note, SingleOrDefault throws an error if more than one result is found.
Item updateItem = Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == itemName);

//Check if the Item exists in the list
if(updateItem != null)
{
    //If it does, update the time
    updateItem.NOWDATE = newDate;
}
else
{
    //If it doesn't, add a new Item
    Item.Insert(0, new Item
    {
        NOWDATE = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateformat),
        Name = itemName     
    }
}

//Now, sort the items so the ones with the earlier date appear first
Items = Items.OrderByDescending(i => i.NEWDATE);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was very helpful.